# How many blank lines between top level variable assignments or method calls?

Tags: python, django, pep8

PEP8 says to put two blank lines between top level method and class definitions, but what about top level variable assignments or method calls. My specific situation is things like `admin.site.register()` and `urlpatterns = []` and various settings in settings.py among other things. Sometimes it seems like 2 lines makes the most sense (urlpatterns) but sometimes it seems like 1 line makes the most sense (admin.site.register, settings). I like sticking with coding standards as best as I can so I was just wondering if there was any rule on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd just group those logically, like you would in a function.

The double-empty-line rule only applies to function and class definitions at the top level.

The only relevant PEP-8 section here is [*Blank Lines*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) and it states:

> Separate top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.

and

> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.

The Google style guide for Python agrees here and also doesn't add anything more specific. Their [*Blank Lines* section](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Blank_Lines#Blank_Lines) reads:

> Two blank lines between top-level definitions, be they function or class definitions. One blank line between method definitions and between the class line and the first method. Use single blank lines as you judge appropriate within functions or methods.

Comment: Alright sounds good, thanks! It's perfectly OK to use 2 blank lines if it makes sense right? Like if I am making 2 really long lists of objects that are similar in size to a class.

Comment: @semicolon: Personally, I'd not use two blank lines in that case still, because the lists are not functions or classes, but this is a style *guide*, not a style *law*. :-)

Comment: In that case how many lines between the imports and the first non-import lines of code? So far I have always used 2 but that is largely because generally the first non-import line is a class or function. One other thing is how many to use between a class / function and something other than a class / function? Two I presume?

Comment: @semicolon: I'd use 2 as well; separate imports from the rest cleanly. Same for classes / functions and 'other things'.

Comment: Intellij suggests 1 blank line between import and top level variable.

Comment: @Sriram: Then I'm afraid Intellij is not following PEP-8; the default configuration for the `flake8` and `pylint` linters will complain about that.